# how to sort the null objects in a dynamically allocated array of objects, so that the null objects are in the back of the array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a dynamically allocated array of objects. Some of the array is populated by objects  but the other parts are null. When I use a bubble sort to sort the objects in the array it sorts correctly, but the array parts that are null are in  front of the array parts that are populated. Is there any way to push the null objects to the back of the array instead of the front?

picture of what is happening in the array:

```
| null | null | null | object | object |
```

picture of what I want the array to look like:

```
| object| object | null | null | null |
```

Here is my code for my bubble sort:

```
::bubbleSort()
{
  bool flag = true;
  obj temp;
  int j = 0;

  while(flag)
  {
    flag = false;
    j++;

    for(int i = 0; i < (max - j); i++)
    {
      if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
      {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i]= arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = temp;
        flag = true;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

here is how i define my arr:

```
private:
obj *arr;
```

then in my constructor

```
max = 25
arr = new obj[max];
```

Comment: Can you add your bubble sort code also to the question? It will help people in providing answers.

Comment: Wherever you are doing the comparison in your code, instead of considering null to be smaller than everything else, consider it larger than everything else.

Comment: my comparisons are being made in my operator overload of < >, do i need to add some code in there stating that NULL > the strings that the objects are comparing and if so any suggestions?

Comment: `null` has a specific meaning in C++ programming involving pointers; do you just mean objects with a value of 0? I ask because your sample code appears to treat them as values rather than as pointers, but you didn't include the definition of `arr` so I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `std::sort` with a custom comparator:

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](auto *p1, auto *p2) {
    if (p1 == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    if (p2 == nullptr) {
        return true;
    }

    return *p1 < *p2;
});
```

This assumes that your custom type defines `operator<`. You can, of course, use anything else you like to compare them.

If you have to implement your own sorting algorithm, you can still just inline the body of the comparator function into the middle the sorting code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and ya i overloaded the < and > to deal with a string element of  the object. Some of this stuff seems  a bit more advanced then what we have learned, but i will look up some of the unknown stuff and try and add it to my code. thanks again.

Comment: Why limit which types the sort can be used for with `p1->operator<(p2)`? `*p1 < *p2` makes the code much more flexible.

Comment: @kfsone of course, you're right. It was a brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for could be [std::partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition), if all you want is to have the nulls at the back. If you also need sorting for the other values, [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is the right choice. Both allow you to define a comparison which defines the sorting or partitioning order, allowing you to customize how the elements are sorted.